# Sending Javascript to GWT JSNI

Tags: gwt, jsni

I know how to call Javascript from GWT.But I have a javascript function that returns a string so, how could I when that function is called send it to GWT.

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you collect strings from JSNI fn

`public static native String stringExample() /*-{
  return "String1";
}-*/;`

This is how you pass a string to JSNI fn

`public static native void alert(String msg) /*-{
  $wnd.alert(msg);
}-*/;`

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I need to know when I call a javascript function, how to pass it to the java code in gwt.Like if I had a function that returned a string in javascript when i called that function it would send it to the java code to say update a textBox. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @james You just use the functions as Java functions now. The js code has been wrapped in a java function. so in gwt use String gwtString=Class.stringExample(); Class.alert(gwtString);